# elementwise binding in R

Tags: r, vectorization, reduce, elementwise-operations

I want a function `f` such that

`(outer(X, Y, f))[i, j]` is a side-by-side concatenation of the i-th element of X and the j-th element of Y, something like `c(X[i], Y[j])`, or having a similar structure.

Furthermore, I want this result to be such that the process can be repeated, and, in this way we get that

`(outer(outer(X, Y, f), Z, f))[i, j, k]` is a side-by-side concatenation of the i-th element of X, the j-th element of Y, and the k-th element of Z, i.e. something equal, or having a structure similar to that of, `c(X[i], Y[j], Z[k])`.

Ultimately I am aiming for defining a function like this:

```
foo <- function(a.list) {
  Reduce(function(x, y) outer(x, y, f), a.list)
}
```

such that, if

```
A <- foo(list(v_1, ..., v_p))
```

then `dim(A)` will be `c(length(v_1), ..., length(v_p))`, and

```
A[i_1, ..., i_p] == c(v_1[i_1], ..., v_p[i_p])
```

for all valid index sets (i_1, ..., i_p).

For example:

```
> foo(list(LETTERS[1:2], c(3, 4, 5), letters[6:7]))
, , 1

               [,1]           [,2]           [,3]
[1,] c("A", 3, "f") c("A", 4, "f") c("A", 5, "f")
[2,] c("B", 3, "f") c("B", 4, "f") c("B", 5, "f")

, , 2

               [,1]           [,2]           [,3]
[1,] c("A", 3, "g") c("A", 4, "g") c("A", 5, "g")
[2,] c("B", 3, "g") c("B", 4, "g") c("B", 5, "g")
```

(**NOTE**: I don't know if an array of vectors like the result shown in the example above is even valid/possible in R, but I am using expressions like `c("A", 3, "f")` to suggest 'some vector-like object whose elements are "A", 3, and "f"'.)

What can I use for f to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example?  Say `X <- LETTERS[1:5]` and `Y <- 1:5`, what should the result be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `Vectorize()` is your friend here: define `f` to be:

```
f <- Vectorize( function(a,b) c(as.list(a), as.list(b)), SIMPLIFY = FALSE )
```

Then you can do (with your definition of `foo` above):

```
z <- foo(list(LETTERS[1:2], c(3, 4, 5), letters[6:7]))
```

For example you can check that the entries match your example above:

```
> z
, , 1

     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  
[1,] List,3 List,3 List,3
[2,] List,3 List,3 List,3

, , 2

     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  
[1,] List,3 List,3 List,3
[2,] List,3 List,3 List,3

> z[2,2,2]
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "B"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 4

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "g"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to Vectorize.  Your solution solved the problem as I posted it, but now I realize that the optimal behavior would be for the individual cells of the array returned by foo to contain lists, so that, for example, `z[2,2,2]` would be equivalent to `list("B", 4, "g")`, preserving the second element as a numeric, rather than string, value.  I tried to redefine f, still using Vectorize, to achieve this, but I nothing I tried worked.  Is it possible?

Comment: Yes that was bothering me, too, and I tried redefining `f` using `list(list(a,b))`, then the resulting `z` entries *do* retain the distinct modes of the elements, but they are some monstrous nested list. I think this could be fixed by appropriately re-defining the `foo` function, but I didn't get a chance to look at it.

Comment: I finally managed to define `f` so it that the `Reduce/Outer` combination retains the original modes of the elements... I fixed the code above.